# How to convert timezone from string format to POSIX format in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone, posix

I need to convert a timezone in string format (e.g. 'Europe/Paris') to POSIX format (e.g. 'CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.4.0/3') in PHP.

Is there a native function to do this?

Comment: A native PHP function doesn't exist, but one could be written.   I'm curious - what is your use case?  I'm guessing something IoT related?  Also, does it have to be PHP, and have you tried writing your own function?  I'm not sure if you need a primer about POSIX time zones or not, but you might want to read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and also the excellent [POSIX and Olson time zones](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-aix-posix/) article from IBM (written about AIX, but applies universally).  Let me know how to narrow the answer better.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson exactly, I need the POSIX format for IoT. My problem is that I don't want to store the POSIX value in database since it changes every year. I managed to get a script to convert it in Javascript but I'd like to do this in PHP in order to recalculate this each time my IoT device asks the API.

Comment: I wrote [code for this](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter/blob/8b4c77aadf8d0267b79fd235d3bebd1712e49591/src/TimeZoneConverter.Posix/PosixTimeZone.cs#L77-L177) in a .Net/C# library that is MIT licensed.  You're welcome to transpose it to PHP, though the implementation may be quite different depending on PHP time zone functions. I don't plan to author a PHP version.  It's possible someone else has.  It's definitely not something that is small enough to give in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Also, if you can use Azure services, the Azure Maps Time Zone API has a [gettimezonebyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/gettimezonebyid) function that includes a `PosixTz` value in the result.  Would that work for you?

Comment: For the Javascript part, I actually used the script you gave here: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314. I'm not using Azure right now. I'll try to transpose your code to PHP.

Comment: Yep. :)  Though I found later there's a bug that sometimes returns 4 instead of 5 when the transition is on the last occurrence of the month (which is fine for a single year, but not technically correct).  The C# version has a fix for that.  I should update the JS version as well.